# Displaying OpenAI Gym Environment Render In TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, q-learning

I am currently creating a GUI in TKinter in which the user can specify hyperparameters for an agent to learn how to play Taxi-v2 in the openai gym environment, I want to know how I should go about displaying the trained agent playing an episode in the environment in a TKinter window.

Could anyone give me advice on how to go about doing this?

Many thanks!